# Streaming a raw data bytes by byte into gstreamer pipeline

Tags: programming, gstreamer

I have a problem that a gstreamer pipeline which has to take raw data byte by byte into pipeline, and it has to played.

I have used [`appsrc`](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-plugins/html/gst-plugins-base-plugins-appsrc.html) to stream a data chunk by chunk into pipeline but it is not helping me much because in this I used to stream from a file.

But, in my case, I want feed a data byte by byte directly without streaming from file.  Let me know anybody having correct solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stdbuf` to pipe the file buffering the output in chunks of 1 byte:

```
stdbuf -o1 cat file | [...]
```